# What does "seconds on time minutes" mean?

Tags: meaning

When someone says that duty cycle of a machine is "2 sec on time min, to 100%" what does the quote mean? I know the meaning of "on time" but the combination of words doesn't come to me.

[Product details and image](http://blog.naver.com/hrnsrn/220508289394)

[image]

Comment: I'm an engineer and I don't know that 'on time' means in this context. Need more info anyway, duty cycle can refer to operating speeds in PWM and also on/off cool-down mode for device operation and both of these are relevant to *many* machines. Best asked at one of the engineering stackexchange sites...

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that "2 sec on time min, to 100%" means roughly "the 'on' time must be at least 2 seconds; it can be as high as 100% of the time".

Comment: @LamarLatrell There is no further information and this is the matter to me also. Just the short quotation is all. Thanks.

Comment: But what type of machine is it? What are you doing with it? Why do you need to know/what is the concern?

Comment: @ruakh, that is the **opposite** of the general understanding of duty cycle. This is an engineering term and is effectively arbitrary until you're taught what it means, but unfortunately it is an overloaded term and the given information doesn't allow us (me at least) to distinguish which meaning is relevant.

Comment: @LamarLatrell: I know what duty cycle means. (I am am engineer by training, though by trade I'm a software developer instead.) The OP's phrase appeared as the value in a field marked "Duty Cycle" in a standard table, so (if my interpretation is right) the reason it's the opposite of the usual meaning is that the person filling out the table had to make do with what the fields it provided.

Comment: @LamarLatrell: (But if you can provide an interpretation that's more consistent with how "duty cycle" is usually used, I'm all ears.)

Comment: @LamarLatrell It' a gas generator and I translate its brochure. Thanks.

Comment: If it is in a brochure, I suggest you use a scanner or your phone to make an image of the page. You can then post the image here so that we can see the phrase in context.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I wanted to that but I thought it would be a trouble. But you want that I attach a link. Thanks a lot. http://blog.naver.com/hrnsrn/220508289394

Comment: @ruakh Oh wow, I see my confusion - I read 'min' as **minute** ... I agree with you, your interpretation is much clearer. I was thinking more slowly than I was reading (and typing).

Answer (score 1):

> When someone says that duty cycle of a machine is "2 sec on time min, to 100%" what does the quote mean?

Here, *min* means *minimum*, not minutes; and *on time* means the *time it is in the ON setting / position*.

The sentence as a whole means the device is (to be)

> switched on for at least 2 seconds in each cycle, and switched on for up to 100% of the cycle.

Comment: @ruakh Apologies for the duplication - I normally go through the comments but must have neglected to this time around. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I'll delete this one. +1 to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here 'on time' refers to the time when the signal is high.

2 sec. On time to 100 means that machine runs for 2 out of 100 secs.
That means 2 percent.

Comment: I think this is not correct.  @ruakh has it right.  the duty cycle can be  as high as 100% (always on) and at low end the duty cycle is physically limited because the shortest time the machine can be on before turning back off is 2 seconds.

Comment: @Jim I deeply appreciate your delicate comment.